# Cannot boot from USB created by Startup Disk Creator

Tags: boot, partitioning, 15.10, startup-disk-creator

First I zeroed out the entire USB flash drive:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

And then I used [`fdisk(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk) to create a type `c` W95 FAT32 (LBA) partition on it and formatted the partition as FAT32:

```
mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb1
```

And then I used Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator to make it a bootable Ubuntu USB stick (the .iso file is verified and not at fault). However, whenever I use the drive to boot I get a `Boot error` message. What's going wrong? How to fix this?
Edit: No other distributions (Fedora, Debian, etc.) on other bootable USB disk creators (UnetBootin, etc.) work. The tool runs on Ubuntu 15.10; the file used is of Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Version 15.10? (I just recently came across a bug for this, I can dig out the bug report and I think there's a fix in there but I should probably make sure it's 15.10 that you're using, first.)

Comment: @KGIII Yes, this is on 15.10

Comment: Looks to be in triage status. Even though it says 'beta' in the description - it appears to have made it through. Check [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1499746) and specifically response #23.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator is sometimes buggy. Use `dd` command instead.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M; sync
```

Wait for it to write to the device. That's it. Here `bs` refers to `Byte Size`

Comment: formatting the first partition to vfat beforehand is completely useless, since you overwrite the whole device with `dd`.

Comment: can also create bootable usb without `bs=4M; sync` in above command. this is not compulsory... it is worked in my case .

Comment: @Linux yup. but `bs` speeds things up

Comment: I prefer add status=process at the end of command : **sudo dd if=pat_to_.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress**

Answer (score 4):

Use built-in **Disks** tool (`gnome-disk-utility`) to create the **Ubuntu installation media** properly.

Open **Disks** - select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right.

Choose the **ISO file** and the **USB drive** to write it to and **start restoring**.

Comment: My computer uses BIOS. I have tried this. Every time I plug the USB drive in and boot, it's stuck on the BIOS POST screen.

Comment: @ThePiercingPrince : Every computer has a Basic Input Output System - Did you change the boot order to boot from USB ? - Did you try another USB drive ? :)

Comment: Yes, I have tried another USB drive. I can't go into the BIOS settings, the computer is stuck.

Comment: @ThePiercingPrince : On many machines you can select where to boot from by pressing one of the F keys e.g. F8 or F10 or F12- please try this. :)

Comment: I have tried that, my computer's boot menu key is normally ESC. This is what happens on my computer when I try to boot from the created USB key: 1. I plug the USB drive into the USB port, and then turn on the computer. 2. After a beep, the BIOS screen shows. I tried all keys, including ESC, F8, F12 and others but nothing happens. If I leave the computer on it's own, the BIOS screen just stays there, forever. This doesn't happen without the USB drive.

Comment: @ThePiercingPrince Is that a EFI only image?

Comment: This method worked for me. It should marked as accepted. The *Disk Startup Creator* didnot work.

Answer (score -3):

You have formatted it from FAT32 and FAT32 is only for Windows/MS-DOS booting and not Ubuntu, so zero it again but choose EXT3/4 and make the Ubuntu Startup Disk again and boot from USB.

Comment: This isn't right. Formatting fat32 is correct

Comment: @Zanna is right as always :)